# update query not updating table in transactions

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I m trying to get and update data at same time but after getting data transaction is rolled back, because table is not updating.
Controller -

```
public function addAmount()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('balance_id', 'Balance Id', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('farmer_id', 'farmer_id', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('amount', 'amount', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('amount_discount', 'discount', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('payment_mode', 'payment mode', 'required|trim');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            $data = array(
                'amount'                 => form_error('amount'),
                'balance_id' => form_error('balance_id'),
                'farmer_id'  => form_error('farmer_id'),
                'amount_discount'        => form_error('amount_discount'),
                'payment_mode'           => form_error('payment_mode'),
            );
            $array = array('status' => 'fail', 'error' => $data);
            echo json_encode($array);
        } else {
            $id =$this->generate_otp();

            $data = array(
                'farmer_id'       => $this->input->post('farmer_id'),
                'balance_id'      => $this->input->post('balance_id'),
                'amount_paid'     => $this->input->post('amount'),
                'paying_date'     => $this->input->post('date'),
                'amount_discount' => $this->input->post('amount_discount'),
                'description'     => $this->input->post('description'),
                'payment_mode'    => $this->input->post('payment_mode'),
                'payment_id'     =>$id,            
            );

            $inserted_id = $this->advance_model->amount_deposit($data);
            echo '<pre>'; print_r($inserted_id); echo ("</pre>"); exit();
            $array = array('status' => 'success', 'error' => '');
            echo json_encode($array);
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
public function amount_deposit($data)
    {
            $this->db->trans_start(); // Query will be rolled back
            $paid_amount     = $data['amount_paid'];
            $this->db->insert('tbl_pay_amount', $data);
            $inserted_id = $this->db->insert_id();
            if ($data['balance_id'] != null) {
               $query = $this->db->select('balance,balance_id,reason')
                ->from('tbl_balance')
                ->where('balance_id', $data['balance_id'])
                ->get();
                return $query->row();
                if(!empty($query)){
                    $b =$query['balance'];
                    $balance =$b - $paid_amount;
                }
            $this->db->update('tbl_balance', array('balance' => $balance));

            }

            $this->db->trans_complete(); # Completing transaction

            if ($this->db->trans_status() === false) {

                $this->db->trans_rollback();
                return false;
            } else {
                $this->db->trans_commit();

                return json_encode(array('invoice_id' => $inserted_id, 'sub_invoice_id' => 1));
            }
        }
```

When amount to be added the balance amount need to be update automatically, but now transaction is roll back because not able to update balance amount after getting it from same table, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the combination of tags? `laravel` and `codeigniter`, and your does not have `jquery`.

Comment: @UmairKhan codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added foreach loop and removed return statement now it's working fine.

```
public function amount_deposit($data)
    {
            $this->db->trans_start(); // Query will be rolled back
            $paid_amount     = $data['amount_paid'];
            $this->db->insert('tbl_pay_amount', $data);
            $inserted_id = $this->db->insert_id();
            if ($data['balance_id'] != null) {
               $query = $this->db->select('balance,balance_id,reason')
                ->from('tbl_balance')
                ->where('balance_id', $data['balance_id'])
                ->get();
                $result = $query->result();
            }
            if (!empty($result) && isset($result)) {

            foreach ($result as $key => $balance_value) {
                $balance_id    = $balance_value->balance_id;
                $balanceAmount = $balance_value->balance;
                $balance =      $balanceAmount - $paid_amount;
            }
               
                 $this->db->where('balance_id', $balance_id);
                 $this->db->update('tbl_balance', array('balance' => $balance));
            }                    
            $this->db->trans_complete(); # Completing transaction
            if ($this->db->trans_status() === false) {
                $this->db->trans_rollback();
                return false;
            } else {
                $this->db->trans_commit();
                return json_encode(array('invoice_id' => $inserted_id, 'sub_invoice_id' => 1));
            }
    }
```